# how to retrieve image or text files using path in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

What exactly I want from this file is first I did data set collection on the basis of flash. In dat I considerd swf and flv files. Using Java Script and eclipse platform we need to display webpages on java, I displayed that one. Now in the same program i need a code to fetch a file path from desktop and display it on the eclipse frame like web page
display, I need to fetch a file like a flv and swf. But now at least i have to display some txt files and images. Please help me

```
package browser;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;

public class modifiedcode extends JFrame {
    public JPanel address_panel, window_panel;
    public JLabel address_label;
    public JTextField address_tf;
    public JEditorPane window_pane, tree_pane, attr_pane;
    public JScrollPane window_scroll, tree_scroll, attr_scroll;
    TextArea t1, t2;
    public JButton address_b;
    private Go go = new Go();

    public modifiedcode() throws IOException {
        // Define address bar
        address_label = new JLabel(" address: ", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        address_tf = new JTextField("http://www.yahoo.com", 25);
        address_tf.setBounds(80, 10, 150, 30);
        address_label.setBounds(10, 10, 70, 30);
        address_tf.addActionListener(go);
        address_b = new JButton("Go");
        address_b.setBounds(240, 10, 50, 30);
        address_b.addActionListener(go);
        address_panel = new JPanel();
        address_panel.setLayout(null);
        window_pane = new JEditorPane("http://www.yahoo.com") {
            public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
                return true;
            }
        };
        JPanel noWrapPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        noWrapPanel.add(window_pane);
        window_pane.setContentType("text/html");
        window_pane.setEditable(false);

        t1 = new TextArea();
        t1.setBounds(650, 380, 300, 250);
        t2 = new TextArea();
        t2.setBounds(650, 50, 300, 280);
        JLabel l = new JLabel("Tree");
        l.setBounds(650, 30, 300, 10);

        JScrollPane window_scroll = new JScrollPane();
        window_scroll
                .setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        window_scroll
                .setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        window_scroll.setViewportView(noWrapPanel);
        window_scroll.setBounds(10, 50, 600, 600);
        window_scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        window_pane.setBounds(10, 50, 600, 600);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Web browser");
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(null);
        // pane.add(window_pane);
        pane.add(window_scroll);
        pane.add(t2);
        pane.add(address_label);
        pane.setVisible(true);
        pane.add(address_tf);
        pane.add(address_b);
        pane.add(l);
        pane.add(t1);
        f.setContentPane(pane);
        f.setSize(1000, 700);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public class Go implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            try {
                window_pane.setPage(address_tf.getText());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) { // new URL() failed
                window_pane.setText("MalformedURLException: " + e);
            } catch (IOException e) { // openConnection() failed
                window_pane.setText("IOException: " + e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        modifiedcode wb = new modifiedcode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read ["how to ask" guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). When asking, take some time to read your question before posting and mind your spelling and grammar. When writing lousy question your question is more likely to be just ignored.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch a file from the path you can use JFrame.class.getResourceAsFile(). This will locate a resource on the classpath.